# Rake, TestFirst, Error, Rspec Config Failed, Learn_Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, test-first

I have done an extensive search within the Q&As and have yet to find a solution, I hope you can guys can help.

I am currently attempting the TestFirst (Learn_Ruby TestFirst) and can't even get pass the the first test for 00_hello. When I type in rake before creating the hello.rb as requested I get a long error message- not the one liner error message mentioned in the task.

Input ***rake***

```
   (in /Users/yanique/Desktop/learn_ruby)
       /Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1018:in `block in requires='
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1018:in `each'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1018:in `requires='
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:101:in `block in process_options_into'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:100:in `each'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:100:in `process_options_into'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec            /Users/yanique/Desktop/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/Users/yanique/Desktop/learn_ruby/00_hello -I/Users/yanique/Desktop/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

Running ***gem list***

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler (1.6.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.3)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rspec (3.0.0, 2.99.0)
rspec-core (3.0.1, 2.99.0)
rspec-expectations (3.0.1, 2.99.0)
rspec-mocks (3.0.1, 2.99.1)
rspec-support (3.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.3)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.1.0)
```

**rvm info**

```
ruby-2.1.1:

system:
uname:       "Darwin yaniques-air.home 13.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13     PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
system:      "osx/10.9/x86_64"
bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)"
zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)"

rvm:
version:      "rvm 1.25.27 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
updated:      "9 days 2 hours 44 seconds ago"
path:         "/Users/yanique/.rvm"

ruby:
interpreter:  "ruby"
version:      "2.1.1p76"
date:         "2014-02-24"
platform:     "x86_64-darwin12.0"
patchlevel:   "2014-02-24 revision 45161"
full_version: "ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]"

homes:
gem:          "/Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1"
ruby:         "/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1"

binaries:
ruby:         "/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby"
irb:          "/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb"
gem:          "/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/gem"
rake:         "/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake"

environment:
PATH:         "/Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby- 2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/yanique/.rvm/bin"
GEM_HOME:     "/Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1"
GEM_PATH:     "/Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1:/Users/yanique/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global"
MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1"
IRBRC:        "/Users/yanique/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/.irbrc"
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       ""
```

***rvm is a function***

```
yaniques-air:~ yanique$ type rvm | head -n1
rvm is a function
yaniques-air:~ yanique$ rake --version
rake, version 10.1.0
```

Tried ***bundle install***

```
yaniques-air:00_hello yanique$ bundle install
Using rake 10.1.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using rspec-support 3.0.0
Using rspec-core 3.0.1
Using rspec-expectations 3.0.1
Using rspec-mocks 3.0.1
Using rspec 3.0.0
Using bundler 1.6.1
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I am expecting a short error when inputting rake without the corresponding hello.rb but definitely not such an extensive error. Nothing seems to be working and I feel I am at an impasse. Sorry for the long post just trying to cover my bases.

**Here's the rakefile that was included in the learn_ruby directory** (I tried adding require 'ruby gems' to it but that did not help either)

```
gem 'rspec', '~>2'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => :spec

desc "run tests for this lab"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
lab = Rake.application.original_dir
task.pattern = "#{lab}/*_spec.rb"
task.rspec_opts = [ "-I#{lab}", "-I#{lab}/solution", '-f documentation', '-r ./rspec_config']
task.verbose = false
end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have `spec_helper` file in your test folder?

Comment: That's a $1000 question.. :)

Comment: Rookie mistake! I remember running it last night but it disappeared. I did rspec --innit again and now its back and everything seems to be running smoothly. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall **all** the `rspec` related gems, **all versions**, then reinstall the last 2.x version

```
gem install -v '< 3.0.0' rspec
```

Try `rake` again from the root directory.